# R: replace or delete part of string after certain combination of letters

Tags: r, replace

I have two datasets each has around 100 variables that have similar names with some minor differences. The variable names in dataset 1 are, CHILD1xxx child1xxx, and the variable names in dataset 2 are, CHILD2xxx child2xxx

For each of the datasets, I want to systematically get rid of the number (i.e.1 or 2) so that the variable names are all CHILDxxx or childxxx.

I was thinking about using **str_replace** or **str_replace_all** but wasn't sure what kind of regular expression I would use to capture the above criteria. I would greatly appreciate any insights on this.

**UPDATES 11/28/22**

The final working code looks like this for replacing names in the entire dataset, as suggested by @Josh White:

```
colnames(DATASET)<-gsub("^(child)\\d+(.*)", "\\1\\2", colnames(DATASET), ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using `gsub()`.

It captures the word "child" (ignoring case), and any combination of characters (or none) after a number (`\\d+` will capture a set of digits next to each other, so the number can be anything from 0 to `Inf`). Using capture groups (the things in brackets), we returns the things before and after the digits, but not the digits `"\\1\\2"`.

```
x <- c("CHILD1xxx", "child2yyy", "Child23hello")
gsub("^(child)\\d+(.*)", "\\1\\2", x, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

```
[1] "CHILDxxx"   "childyyy"   "Childhello"
```

Another approach could be to remove all numbers but this could be problematic if other numbers come up later on in the string.

```
gsub("\\d", "", x)
```

```
[1] "CHILDxxx"   "childyyy"   "Childhello"
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove a substring form a string, you can conveniently use `str_remove`. Since the substring to be removed is one or more digits, define `\\d+` as the pattern for the removal:

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(x, "\\d+")
[1] "CHILDxxx"   "childyyy"   "Childhello"
```

Data:

```
x <- c("CHILD1xxx", "child2yyy", "Child23hello")
```

**EDIT**:

if the replacements should be implemented in column (variable) names in a dataframe, then you could use `str_remove` together with `rename_with`:

```
df %>%
  rename_with(~str_remove(., "\\d+"))
  CHILDxxx childyyy Childhello SomeOther
1       NA       NA         NA        NA
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  CHILD1xxx = NA,
  child2yyy = NA,
  Child23hello = NA,
  SomeOther = NA
)
```